# Add a coded column to an existing table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a select statement, pulling invoice value so far this Year, by Month. I am trying to add a column to show different targets for each month. So I can compare the actual values against target each week or each month. The below query repeats 260000 each month, how can I change this to a different currency value per month or show zero where the answer is not yet known?

```
SELECT 
FORMAT (SUM(dbo.ARInvoices.arpInvoiceSubtotalBase), 'C0') AS "Total",  
DATEPART(month, dbo.ARInvoices.arpInvoiceDate) as "Month", '260000' AS TARGET
FROM dbo.ARInvoices     
WHERE dbo.ARInvoices.arpInvoiceDate >= '{%Current Year%}' 
GROUP BY DATEPART(month, dbo.ARInvoices.arpInvoiceDate)
```

This gives a result of

[image]

Ideally, the result would be something like the below:

```
MONTH   TARGET   ACTUAL
Jan     $260000   $223735
Feb     $383000   $69299
Mar     $400000   $0
etc
```

Comment: This is the same as your previous question. If your question gets closed, improve the question, don't ask it again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add column to existing table with custom numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60179638/add-column-to-existing-table-with-custom-numbers)

Comment: `FORMAT(260000, 'C') As Target`

Comment: `I don't think the Target value needs to be stored anywhere else` So you want to hardcode the `Target` value in your query ? And for all the years + months ? And change the query whenever the `Target` is revised ? Don't you think this is very very impractical ?

Comment: Thank you @DaleK I wasn't sure how to repost the question after I had edited it.

Comment: @ESwift editing it will put it in the review queue to be considered for re-opening.

Comment: Possibly @Squirrel, but I wasn't sure how else to do it and being target numbers they would change yearly or half yearly.

Comment: create a table to store the `target` value by year and month. Then in your query `join` to this table

Comment: @squirrel - thank you I have done this and pulled the join, it works well. except that I need to have the 'Target' included in the aggregate or group by. Aggregate obviously changed the target amount, and group by adds extra rows. Any ideas? I'm sorry for all the questions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use derived table / sub-query / cte to calculate the monthly total and then `JOIN` to your target table

```
SELECT A.Total, A.Month, T.Target
FROM
(
    SELECT SUM(dbo.ARInvoices.arpInvoiceSubtotalBase) AS Total
           ,  DATEPART(month, dbo.ARInvoices.arpInvoiceDate) as Month
    FROM   dbo.ARInvoices     
    WHERE  dbo.ARInvoices.arpInvoiceDate >= '{%Current Year%}' 
    GROUP BY DATEPART(month, dbo.ARInvoices.arpInvoiceDate)
) A
LEFT JOIN dbo.Targets T ON A.Month = T.Month
```

Comment: thank you,@squirrel  very close. Is now telling me that date is incompatible with int. I am presuming this is something to do with the way I have created the table?

Comment: You probably created the `Month` column as `string` in the table. Should use `int`